# Insert data from one SQL Server table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, primary-key

I have to insert data from one table into another. The problem is that the table where the data has to be inserted into has a primary key.

Suppose there are 2 tables A and B.

- A has two columns `id` (primary key) and `name`
- B has two columns `id` and `name`

How can we insert data from table B into table A with the primary key column?

Comment: What **datatypes** are your columns? Are any of them `IDENTITY` columns?

Answer (score 0):

For example there are 2 tables A & B as you stated.

```
insert into A (id,name) values(2, 'Testing');
insert into B (id, foreign_key, name) values(1, 2, 'Hello');
```

Both tables have a primary key. Primary key of table A is used as a foreign key to connect to the table B so that they interact with each other

Here is its design:

[image]